# What is the relation between trees and gods?

Tags: gods, plants, navagraha, nakshatra

I heard of Navagraha vana(garden of trees representing 9 planets), Nakshatra vana(trees representing 27 stars), Devatha vana(trees representing each god).

What are those plants? Does worshiping give the equal benefit of worshiping murthi in the temple? Are there any special benefits? If possible, can you also attempt to describe how to worship each of them with one-liners!

Comment: @Eshan Singh How was your edit approved, when you just added the word "the" in title?

Answer (score 5):

> What are those plants?

I can answer this for the Navagrahas at least.Not sure about the Nakshatra plants but the 9 Navagraha plants are well-known.For example see [this](http://www.sushmajee.com/stories/topics/trees-planets.htm) site.

And the Scripture which mention about these plants is the [Yajnavalkya Smriti](http://www.astrojyoti.com/pdfs/DevanagariFiles/06Yagyavalkya_Smriti.pdf).

> [image]
>
> **Arka**(Sunplant),**Palasa**(Soma),**Khadira**(Mangal),**Apamarga**(Budha),**Pippala**(Brihaspati),**Udumvara**(Sukra),**Shami**(Sani),**Durva**(Rahu)
>   and **Kusa**(Ketu) ,are,in order,the sacrificial fuels of the Nine
>   Planets.
>
> **(Yajnavalkya Smriti verse 302)**

The next verse then says how to use these plants as oblations in Navagraha Yajnas.

> With each class of Samidh,soaked with honey ,clarified butter,curd,or
>   thickened milk ,oblations,either 108 or 28 in number should be
>   offered.(Verse 303)

So,these 9 plants are used as sacrificial materials in Navagraha Yajnas.I don't know if they are themselves worshiped as representatives of the 9 Grahas,probably they are not.

Comment: @SreeCharan I knew that this Q exist(don't remember now how,probably from suggested/related Qs that show up at the right hand side)..Last nite while i was browsing thru YS i thought i shd answer this..And "these" means what?Which other Q r u referring to?

Comment: Many other related to dharmashastras. You answer many questions.. :)